# Eclipse open a file contained in the project

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I open a file contained within the project by specifying only the filename? I'm looking for the equivalent of "Open Type" (Shift-Control-T) but for a (non-Java) file? In other words, I know the filename but not the exact path. IntelliJ has this feature - Go To File.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do "Open resource" and the shortcut is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: Yep. This also supports wildcards, which is very useful.

Comment: Was looking for something like this for ages. Thanks!

Comment: It's probably obvious, but the correct Mac hotkey is CMD + SHIFT + R

Answer (score 4):

I needed a bit more out of the default Resource search that comes with Eclipse. I had been using GotoFile plugin ([1](https://web.archive.org/web/20121013050850/http://www.muermann.org/gotofile) or [2](https://github.com/adelarsq/eclipse-gotofile-plugin-kai)) with a lot of success till some time back.

The best part of it is `fuzzy-search`. Thus for example if you had to search for `struts-config.xml` you could type in `strc` or `sr-c` etc. This was a huge time saver for me. With the default `Open Resource` you must do one of the following (As an example, searching for `struts-config.xml` using `Open Resource`):

1. Type the characters in sequence : `struts`
2. If you wanted to leave out a few characters in between to simulate a poor man's fuzzy search, you would type : `st*config`
3. Some types (Java classes) support Camel Case search. Thus to search for MyClass.java, you could type `MC`

With the plugin however, the fuzzy search takes out the tediousness of searching. I have found it incredibly useful but am not sure whether it still works on Indigo. The last I used it on was Eclipse Helios. I'll report back about how well it works in Indigo SR2.

**Installation**

It seems I could not get the GotoFile plugin to work from the update site. So I went old-school on it and tried copying the plugin directly to the  eclipse/plugins folder. That worked for both 64-bit and 32-bit Eclipse Indigo SR2 as the following snapshots show :

Eclipse 3.7.2 - 32-bit (Inside Ubuntu in a Parallels VM). 
[image]

Eclipse 3.7.2 - 64-bit (In OSX Snow Leopard)

[image]

### The Good Stuff - Fuzzy search

Searching for a file called `user_helper.rb` using the fuzzy search term `ushlrb` :

[image]